# filter json data on nifi using route on attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a source which produce json data and each file contains only one record  as below 
file1:-

```
{"X":"12","Y":"23","r":"3","V":"0"}
```

file2:-

```
{"r":"32","Y":"24","x":"3","V":"12"}
```

file3:-

```
 {"v":"1","r":"23","x":"3","y":"23"}
```

now in nifi I want to filter all files if  y=23 and v=0  to one destination and remaining to different destination.
can any one help me

my nifi flow:-
[image]

my route on attribute processor
[image]

can any one please help my to write a condition so that i can filter data as per above requirements

Comment: Use expression functions `equals` & `and`. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#and

Answer (score 1):

Extract the values for **`y,v`** in **`EvaluateJSONPath`** processor and add new expression in **`RouteOnAttribute`** processor to filter out required flowfiles.

Try with below expression using [NiFi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#equals):

```
${y:equals('23'):and(${v:equals('0')})}
```

Comment: Hi @shu  I have tried above expression but still unable to filter

Comment: @RahulVarma This is really the answer but why it doesn't work? Explain more to investigate the reason.

Comment: Also Indicate where you get stuck, in the extraction or the routing.